# I am not able to run parcel from vs code

Tags: npm, three.js

File C:\Users\bartp\AppData\Roaming\npm\parcel.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information,
see about_Execution_Policies at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170

The above is what I keep seeing after trying to load index.html from the terminal in vs Code.

I used the code
*parcel ./src/index.html*

How do I change this?

Comment: The link you posted has everything you need to know to fix this problem.

Comment: Thanks, but the link leads me nowhere when I paste it in the browser. The added microsoft link

Comment: Try clicking on it now. I fixed the link in your question.